# "Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, docker, fastify

I am getting an error on pg.connect not defined. In the Handler module.

---

I am trying to create a table using postgres in fastify. I have and handle routes folder that handles the routes and sends API requests. When I hit the http://localhost:3000/initDB route the error says

```
{
    "statusCode": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined"
}
```

this is my Table module, looks like **Table module** is not getting fastify instance how can i solve this issue.

```
const fastify = require("../server");

const Table = async (req, reply) => {
  await fastify.pg.connect(onConnect);
  function onConnect(err, client, release) {
    if (err) return reply.send(err);
    client.query(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"name" varchar(30),"lastname" varchar(30));',
      function onResult(err, result) {
        release();
        reply.send(err || result);
      }
    );
  }
};

module.exports = {
  Table,
};
```

Routes file,

I have handled routes here,

```
//const fastify = require("fastify");
const { Table } = require("./Handler/CreateTable");
const { GetUsers, PostUsers } = require("./Handler/Handler");
const CreateTable = {
  handler: Table,
};
const getUsers = {
  handler: GetUsers,
};

const postUsers = {
  handler: PostUsers,
};

async function routes(fastify, options) {
  fastify.get("/initDB", Table);
  fastify.get("/users", getUsers);
  fastify.post("/users/create", postUsers);
}

module.exports = routes;
```

server.js file,

```
const fastify = require("fastify")({ logger: true });
fastify.register(require("fastify-postgres"), {
  connectionString: `postgres://${process.env.POSTGRES_USER}:${process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@${process.env.POSTGRES_SERVICE}:${process.env.POSTGRES_PORT}/${process.env.POSTGRES_DB}`,
});

module.exports = fastify;
fastify.register(require("./routes"));

// Run the server
const start = () => {
  fastify.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", (err, address) => {
    if (err) {
      fastify.log.error(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  });
};
start();
```

[image]
This is error, please tell me how can I solve this error.

pg connect error to be solved

type here

Answer (score 1):

In general exporting a global variable like this, is a bad practice. The application will be extremely hard to test

```
const fastify = require("fastify")({ logger: true });

module.exports = fastify;
```

So, I would suggest to read [this article about it](https://backend.cafe/how-to-test-a-fastify-application)

---

Regarding your issue instead, you need to change the code to:

```js
const Table = async function (req, reply) {
  await this.pg.connect(onConnect);
  // ...
}
```

Note that, when you use **named functions** (instead of anonymous functions) the `this` context is the fastify instance.

You are getting undefined because the `fastify` variable you are referring to does not have that decorator loaded yet, so `fastify.pg` in that file returns `undefined`.

Finally, you should install [`@fastify/postgres`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fastify/postgres) instead of [`fastify-postgress`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-postgres) because the last one is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if fastify has `pg` property by CTRL + clicking on it on the line where you imported it. fastify class/module should be opened. There you can check the class's properties and methods.
2. You are passing `onConnect` variable as a parameter to the function. This variable is not defined anywhere:

```
const fastify = require("../server");

const Table = async (req, reply) => {
  await fastify.pg.connect(onConnect); // <= Check if you have defined onConnect variable anywhere.
  function onConnect(err, client, release) {
    if (err) return reply.send(err);
    client.query(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "users" ("id" SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,"name" varchar(30),"lastname" varchar(30));',
      function onResult(err, result) {
        release();
        reply.send(err || result);
      }
    );
  }
};

module.exports = {
  Table,
};
```

Comment: `onConnect` is the name of the function declared on the next line.

Comment: Have you tried async method?